# OPC UA address differ between server and client

Tags: opc-ua, kepserverex

I have created a channel and device on KepserverEx with a couple of tags.
In the configuration, I have set the address of a node as:

```
ns=3;s=Channel1.Device1.Start
```

And if I browse for the same node using UeExpert I find the NodeId as

```
nsu=KEPServerEX;ns=2;s=Channel1.Device1.Start
```

Which is what I need to use in my C# Client.

Why the value of **ns**(namespace index) is not the same as I have defined in the Server?

Comment: check for the node namespaceArray (Server_NamespaceArray nodeId-"ns=0;i=2255"), there might be the case the there is no namespace available at index-3.

Comment: The NamespaceArray has three strings, [0],[1],[2]
In KepserverEx I need to enter ns=3, maybe OPC UA and KepserverEx has different start of an array. 0 vs 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about KepserverEx, but in general the namespace index of a node is not static, but is (re-)defined dynamically in a server when a model is loaded/instantiated.
The only static namespace index is 0 for the default opc ua nodeset.

So, if you have only two namespaces (+ the default nodeset) defined in your server, the namespaces will have the indicies 1 and 2.

If the client doesn't know the index of a namespace in a specific server, it can request the list of namespaces and can so resolve the right index for a specific namespace name.

Comment: OK, so I need to look up the namespace to get the correct one.